# Selenium automation to go to next page and freezes

Tags: excel, selenium, internet-explorer, automation

I use the below code to go to next page. It works as expected but after that the 
browser freezes. Does not retrieve any data from the next webpage.

http://www.forbes.com/companies/icbc/

```
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        for(int i=1;i<3;i++)
        {
        WebElement tab=driver.findElement(By.className("large"));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        String text= tab.getText();
        System.out.println(text);

        String industry=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Industry')]//following::dd[1]")).getText();
        System.out.println(industry);

      Workbook workbook;
            try 
            {
                workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("D:\\Dummy.xls"));
                WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("D:\\Dummy.xls"),workbook);
                WritableSheet sheet=copy.getSheet(0);
                Label lable = new Label(0,i,industry);
                sheet.addCell(lable);
                copy.write();
                copy.close();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //WebElement nextPage=driver.findElement(By.className("next-number"));
            WebElement nextPage=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'next-number')]"));
            nextPage.click();
```

I am getting the error :

> NoSuchWindowEception: Unable find element on a closed window

I'm using IE to automate the process.

Comment: Provided line seem to be ok. Are you sure that it is the cause of your issue? Share more code.

Comment: do you have `driver.close()` or `driver.quit()` in your code by any chance?

Comment: Yes @After
 public void tearDown() throws Exception {
  driver.quit();
  driver.close();
 }

Comment: so it goes to the next page and then does nothing ? Can you tell us what should happen after that ?

Comment: It's supposed to go to the next page and fetch the details as in the code but its not doing that.